# adjusting arrays in two column document

Tags: two-column

i'm trying to create t metrics in two column latex document, everything went well but column one array is overwrite on column two as shown:[image: how can i fix this?]
i wrote the arrays as:

```
        \begin{scriptsize}  
 \begin{multicols}{2} \
     \[CPU = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
    10 & 90 & 90 & 55 \\
    50 & 20 & 20 & 72 \\
    30 & 20 & 20 & 72 \\
10 & 40 & 40 & 72 \\
20 & 40 & 40 & 72 \\
20 & 50 & 50 & 55 \\
90 & 20 & 20 & 15 \\
20 & 10 & 10 & 70 \\
20 & 10 & 10 & 70 \\
20 & 15 & 15 & 70 \\
90 & 10 & 10 & 33
 \end{array} \right]  Memory = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
 48 & 256 & 256 & 128 \\
 128 & 256 & 256 & 148 \\
 64 & 256 & 256 & 148 \\
 48 & 168 & 168 &  148 \\
 64 & 168 & 168 & 148 \\
 64 & 168 & 168 & 64 \\
 168 & 128 & 128 & 64 \\
 148 & 96 & 96 & 148 \\
 48 & 32 & 32 & 148 \\
 48 & 32 & 32 & 148 \\
 168 & 64 & 64 & 96 
 \end{array} \right]\]  
\end{multicols}
\[Power = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
2 & 18 & 18 & 11 \\
10 & 4 & 4 & 14 \\
6 & 4 & 4 & 14 \\
2 & 8 & 8 & 14 \\
4 & 8 & 8 & 14 \\
4 & 10 & 10 & 11 \\
18 & 4 & 4 & 3 \\
4 & 2 & 2 & 14 \\
4 & 2 & 2 & 14 \\
4 & 3 & 3 & 14 \\
18 & 2 & 2 & 7

\end{array} \right]\]   
\end{scriptsize}
```

any tips?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! your array is simple to wide to be fit in one column. One possible solution is broke first line of your math into two lines. Do you agree with such solution? However, a short complete document, which we can copy to our computers and compile, would be very helpful.

Comment: One possible solution is broke first line of your math into two lines.    could you clarify it more?

Comment: its works! the problem was that i wrote the arrays inside an itemize environment so they was like this. thank you.

Comment: meanwhile I prepare suggestion how to wrote your equations, see it below.

Answer (score 1):

See, if the following code works for you. In comparison to yours it s changed a way of writing variables `CPU`, `Memory` and `Power`, Than instead of `array` I use `matrix` environment and all matrices into `align`. All this enviromnets is avaliable with `amsmath` package or its improved version `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}   
    \begin{align*}
\mathit{CPU} 
    & = \begin{bmatrix}
    10 & 90 & 90 & 55 \\
    50 & 20 & 20 & 72 \\
    30 & 20 & 20 & 72 \\
    10 & 40 & 40 & 72 \\
    20 & 40 & 40 & 72 \\
    20 & 50 & 50 & 55 \\
    90 & 20 & 20 & 15 \\
    20 & 10 & 10 & 70 \\
    20 & 10 & 10 & 70 \\
    20 & 15 & 15 & 70 \\
    90 & 10 & 10 & 33
        \end{bmatrix} \displaybreak[2]    \\[1ex]
\mathit{Memory}
    & = \begin{bmatrix}
     48  & 256 & 256 & 128  \\
     128 & 256 & 256 & 148  \\
     64  & 256 & 256 & 148  \\
     48  & 168 & 168 &  148 \\
     64  & 168 & 168 & 148  \\
     64  & 168 & 168 & 64   \\
     168 & 128 & 128 & 64   \\
     148 & 96 & 96 & 148    \\
     48  & 32 & 32 & 148    \\
     48  & 32 & 32 & 148    \\
     168 & 64 & 64 & 96
    \end{bmatrix}  \displaybreak[2]    \\[1ex]
\mathit{Power}
    & = \begin{bmatrix}
    2  & 18 & 18 & 11   \\
    10 & 4  & 4  & 14   \\
    6  & 4  & 4  & 14   \\
    2  & 8  & 8  & 14   \\
    4  & 8  & 8  & 14   \\
    4  & 10 & 10 & 11   \\
    18 & 4  & 4  & 3    \\
    4  & 2  & 2  & 14   \\
    4  & 2  & 2  & 14   \\
    4  & 3  & 3  & 14   \\
    18 & 2  & 2  & 7
    \end{bmatrix}                  
    \end{align*}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```